# Apache utf-8 characters in filename

Tags: apache

I can't figure it why I can't open files (photos as a start) that contain utf-8 characters in their file name.

For example, I have the following photo: `José-Antonio.jpg` , the browser outputs it as `Jos%C3%A9-Antonio.jpg` but trying to access it, will return an `404` error code.

I tried and have these settings in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but don't seem to fix it:

```
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddDefaultCharSet ISO-8859-1

IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
```

Any ideas what could go wrong? And btw, it seams the system supports utf-8 encoding...

```
[root@u16641744 01]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`ls` result in a directory containing such files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   6093 Dec 22 17:39 Adoración-de-los-Magos-Botticelli-110x90.jpg
```

But the curios thing is that the output of the following command, is wrong:

```
perl -Mcharnames=:full -CS -wle 'print "\N{EURO SIGN}"'
  |-> outputs: â¬
```

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: @Anagio ... lol, of course :)

Comment: Had to ask. Check out this question on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server

Comment: @Anagio no luck mate... I keep trying over and over again everything I can think of, no luck at all

Comment: What does the errorlog say when you get an unexpected 404?
Turn up the loglevel if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you know folks, I ended up re-installing the system. I would definitely say that the issue was from the host provider with its default install.

So yea, after hours and hours of trying to debug and fix this (I tried Apache tweaking, System encoding, File system checks, ...) ended up finally just installing a

Comment: how did you fix this?